# Curving text in PHP along a path?

Tags: php, imagemagick, inkscape

Is there a way to add curve to text (as seen by the shape "CURVE TEXT" in CustomInk - add text then go to shape settings) in PHP?

Right now I can add an "arch curve" which doesn't rotate the letters, just stretches them and moves them to fit the path, but not the smooth curved text look that CustomInk is using.

Comment: You are aware of Imagemagick examples? http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/#arch

Comment: Can you provide a like to the CURVE TEXT your talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a template using SVG (create in Inkscape or any SVG editor) and then manipulate the XML using PHP. Finally to get some dynamic output, render the modified SVG file using `inkscape` on the command line, to get either bitmap or PDF output. The results will be of excellent quality.